# Trying to create infinite scroll with rxjs and angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having trouble understanding how it can add stream data into my infinite scroll.

I declare my observable variable and page offset

```
products$;
offset: number = 0;
```

Then I i create my observable from one of my services:

```
this.products$ = this.storeService.getProductsLatest(100, this.offset).pipe(
      map(r => fixImages(r, 1000000000))
    )
```

This works so far it gets my 100 products and the page offset is 0

Now I have an function called onScroll that gets triggered every time the container scroll reaches 80% of total height. This should get another 20 products from the next page

```
onScroll() {
    this.products$.pipe(
      flatMap(() => this.storeService.getProductsLatest(20, this.offset++).pipe(
        map(r => fixImages(r, 1000000000))
      )),
    )
  }
```

flatMap doesn't seem to be doing anything here it should be streaming the extra products when I scroll down but it doesn't

Example of my component view:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products$|async">
        {{ prod.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` does not behave as you expect here. I suggest a good alternative to achieve what you expect here.

Declare `products$` as a type of `Subject`. Please note that a `Subject` is an `Observable` as well.

```
onScroll() {
    this.storeService.getProductsLatest(20, this.offset++).pipe(
        map(r => fixImages(r, 1000000000)),
       tap(newData => this.products$.next(newData))
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but nothing seems to be getting added on scroll.

Comment: This concept must work. Check onScroll is actually firing. Also put a console.log(newData) in the argument of tap function body and see whether newData is actually coming in.

Comment: Yeah I already tried to see what was being returned in tap but I am not even seeing that I am already logging to console whenever it gets fired so i am seeing it